# Lync Group Installation - Certificates

Tags: lync, instant-messaging

Lync Server: Server 2008r2 standard sp1, Lync server 2010

Lync Edge: Server 2008r2 standard sp1

Server running SQL: Server Standard 2008, running SQL Express 2008 I believe, can't tell for sure since I didn't set this up. Database collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS (which is listed somewhere as the requirement)

I'm having [lots of fun](http://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/2hsed8/moronic_monday_september_29_2014/ckvn6iq) trying to get Group Chat functioning in Lync 2010, its poor documentation and schizophrenic requirements combined with my absence of skill with deploying Lync is making life really fun.

As you may see if you look at my link outlining my previous troubleshooting, I'm having issues getting the lookup and channel services to stay running - they error out with a long message regarding the certificate not being capable of key exchange. If I attempt to export the MTLS certificate you choose during installation the summary page before finishing does indicate the private keys are not being exported, so it seems like I need to issue a new one.

[The instructions are here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398208.aspx) but like I said, very inconsistent. The last thing I did yesterday was to import my new webserver template-based certificate with exportable private keys and everything Lync-related broke. Not sure if our deployment is very very fragile or poorly put together or if I did something wrong

Has anyone had any luck or experience with this portion of the group chat install? The information I've seen on Technet social pages and on Google hasn't helped me

Answer (score 0):

I saw a similar issue in the past while I was upgrading a Lync environment to Skype for Business. What happened on the older Lync environment was that the SSL keychain wasn´t ok. On that environment some root certificates where missing and some others where duplicated. The Lync environment wasn´t able to fully validate the SSL chain and broke. You might wish to check that as a starting point [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uclobby/2015/06/19/checks-to-do-in-the-lyncskype4b-certificate-store/) is a good URL to a Microsoft blog posting which deals with that issue.